# Set Cursor in datagridview rows only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to have a "Help" cursor in DataGridView, but only from 1st row to end of rows, excluding column header. The code I currently use shows the help cursor everywhere over datagridview control - on column headers and even blank space under rows because I have docked datagridview in panel. It's probably simple, but how can I fix this? I have code to set cursor back to default when leaving DataGridView too.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseMove(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseMove
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DataGridView1
    For r As Integer = 1 To dgv.RowCount - 1
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Help
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseLeave
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will change the cursor to help only when over the cells. It excludes the title row as well as the left column, as well as the background. You can change the condition to exactly suit your needs

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseMove
    Dim myHitTest = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If myHitTest.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso myHitTest.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Help
    Else
        DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should change `Me.Cursor` to `DataGridView1.Cursor` or else you can leave the form's Cursor set as the the Help cursor.

Comment: Verdolino, just one question more. I also need this only if first cell in a current row isn't empty. I tried adding "IsDBNull(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)", but strangely not working. Do I have to put code in different event or what ?

Comment: You are using current row but you should be using myHitTest.RowIndex